# Why ConcurrentSkipListSet.contains requires comparator and not equals

Tags: java, concurrency, set

I am using ConcurrentSkipListSet and using contains method.

As per JAVA doc for contains method

Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that o.equals(e).

But as per my test , it appears that equals method is not used but rather Comparator is mandatory. Please help me understand this anomaly between JAVA spec and implementation

ConcurrentSkipListSet

/**
     * If using comparator, return a ComparableUsingComparator, **else
     * cast key as Comparable, which may cause ClassCastException,**
     * which is propagated back to caller.
     */
    private Comparable comparable(Object key)

at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.comparable(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:663)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.containsKey(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1608)

I am using Oracle JDK 7

Comment: This is perfectly normal behavior for a sorted collection.  The doc from `TreeSet` is probably applicable: "Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.)"

Comment: Java doc for CSLS should have clarified this in bold .

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: note that [`TreeSet.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) has the same misleading sentence in its documentation and apparently it was added deliberately in Java 6.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two questions/concerns, (1) Why does the contains require a `Comparator` or `Comparable`. (2) The Javadoc says it will use the `equals` method.

1. A ConcurrentSkipListSet is a navigable ordered collection so all elements either must maintain a natural order, or you must specify a comparator.
2. I think the Javadoc is stated incorrectly, or at the very least it is misleading. Under the hood, the CSLS will delegate to a ConcurrentSkipListMap.containsKey so it, right now, does not control the contains implementation.  That said, I think there can be an argument to clarify the javadocs.

EDIT:
There is also a `throws` doc for the fact these objects aren't comparable

> ClassCastException - if the specified element cannot be compared with
>   the elements currently in this set

Comment: Disappointed with Java doc here . Never expected it to be so untrue. We tend to take it seriously and hardly debug through implementation to verify everything

Comment: @Amrish Pandey: it’s strongly recommended to consider the purpose and limitations of a class in general, before deciding to use it at all, instead of being surprised at the behavior of one particular method. It isn’t as if `contains` was the only method in this class relying on the order rather than equality.

Comment: @holger majority of people go by Java doc instead of looking up source code for every API they use or learning it the hard way with exceptions. Considering Java doc is widely referred , it should have updated definition for contains. It clearly states it's suppose to use equals() method, hardly anybody would imagine otherwise

Comment: @Amrish Pandey: of course, you should go by Java doc, i.e. before starting to use a class, you should study the *class* documentation. If you understood the purpose of the class, as documented, you didn’t stumble over one wrong documentation of a single particular method. You shouldn’t use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` if you don’t understand its dependency on the ordering. The same applies to `TreeSet`, which has the same documentation bug for ten years now, apparently with very little impact…